# Alfresco: List Object Properties using RESTFul

Tags: json, rest, alfresco, restful-url

I need to list Alfresco Object Properties using RESTFul protocol. I heard that can be done directly from the browser, and get result in a form of JSON, but I couldn't find any examples online. Do I need to authenticate first? Can anyone help me with this one? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean all the properties on a particular node? If so, you will need to authenticate, as you can only fetch properties for a node that the user you're authenticated as has access to

Answer (score 1):

There is an **service/api/metadata** which return a JSON result all the properties of a node.
It accepts 2 variables in the get: `nodeRef=<nodeRef>` and `shortQNames=<true/false>`

The shortQNames is optional and gives by default the full namespace.

An example:

```
{
   "mimetype": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
   "aspects":
   [
       "cm:auditable",
       "sys:referenceable",
       "cm:titled",
       "cm:author",
       "rn:renditioned",
       "sys:localized",
       "cm:versionable"
   ],
   "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/01a6ba5a-2386-4cea-805f-db269075761b",
   "properties":
   {
       "cm:autoVersionOnUpdateProps": false,
       "cm:name": "Dashboard xxxx.xlsx",
       "sys:node-dbid": 3575,
       "sys:store-identifier": "SpacesStore",
       "sys:locale": "null",
       "sys:node-uuid": "01a6ba5a-2386-4cea-805f-db269075761b",
       "cm:creator": "xx.xx",
       "cm:modifier": "xx.xx",
       "cm:versionLabel": "1.17",
       "cm:content": "contentUrl=store://2012/1/8/22/10/50acac4c-11ba-4a2c-b976-7319ad0f2292.bin|mimetype=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet|size=33996|encoding=UTF-8|locale=en_US_|id=1674",
       "cm:autoVersion": true,
       "cm:title": "xxxxxx.xlsx",
       "cm:modified": "Sun Jan 08 22:10:25 CET 2012",
       "cm:author": "RDS",
       "cm:created": "Fri Nov 04 11:26:53 CET 2011",
       "sys:store-protocol": "workspace",
       "cm:initialVersion": true
   },
   "type": "cm:content"
}
```